# \newpage, \pagebreak, and \clearpage within a set of flashcards

Tags: page-breaking, flashcards

I am using the `flashcards` document class, with the `avery5371` option that produces ten double-sided 2"x3.5" cards per page of `letterpaper` geometry.

When I make changes to some cards, rather than reprint the whole set of cards and discard those without changes, I would like to move the new cards to the end of the list and print them alone. It would be helpful, therefore, to be able to start a new page of output before the changed cards begin. But I find that the three commands I know of for starting a new page, `\newpage`, `\pagebreak`, and `\clearpage`, all fail to produce the desired result. The grid of ten cards per sheet continues past these commands unbroken.

Any suggestions on how to get a new page? The last-ditch solution is to start a new file with the changed cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of forcing the modified cards to appear in a new page, you could *comment* the unmodified ones, so they don't show; this can be done with the `comment` environment from the [comment](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/comment) package; a little example (uncommenting-out the line `\includecomment{comment}` you can recover all the cards):

```
\documentclass[avery5371]{flashcards}
\usepackage{comment}

%\includecomment{comment}

\begin{document}

\begin{comment}
\begin{flashcard}{Test one}
Test one
\end{flashcard}

\begin{flashcard}{Test two}
Test two
\end{flashcard}
\end{comment}

\begin{flashcard}{Test three}
Test three
\end{flashcard}

\begin{comment}
\begin{flashcard}{Test four}
Test four
\end{flashcard}
\end{comment}

\begin{flashcard}{Test five}
Test five
\end{flashcard}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, very clever.

Comment: I can find nothing else that works. Breaking the document into sections also fails to stop the relentless progress of the cards...